# MEAN stack http.post request body is empty

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am creating a project in mean stack and i ran into the following issue.

When i try to upload something to my database, the http.post request is doesn't working due to the request body is empty, thus i got a ValidationError in mongoose for the required parameters it should, but doesn't get.

So first I am using a service.ts where I give the parameters i got from a form in the html file. i am using reactive forms and FormData object for this.

```js
addProp(address: string, type: string, size: number, condition: string, year: number,
    numberOfRooms: number, moveableFrom: string, furnitured: boolean, garden: boolean, attic: boolean, pet: boolean,
    smoke: boolean, heatingType: string, elevator: boolean, level: number) {
    

    const propData = new FormData();
    propData.append("address", address);
    propData.append("type", type);
    propData.append("condition", condition);
    propData.append("year", year as unknown as string);
    propData.append("numberOfRooms", numberOfRooms as unknown as string);
    propData.append("moveableFrom", moveableFrom);
    propData.append("furnitured", furnitured as unknown as string);
    propData.append("garden", garden as unknown as string);
    propData.append("attic", attic as unknown as string);
    propData.append("pet", pet as unknown as string);
    propData.append("smoke", smoke as unknown as string);
    propData.append("heatingType", heatingType as unknown as string);
    propData.append("size", size as unknown as string);
    propData.append("elevator", elevator as unknown as string);
    propData.append("level", level as unknown as string);
    this.http
      .post<{ message: string; prop: Property }>(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/props",
        propData
      )
      .subscribe(responseData => {
        this.router.navigate(["/"]);
      });
  }
```

Then it goes to the post request in the backend properties.js

```js
router.post(
  "",
  req => {
    const prop = new Property({
      address: req.body.address,
      type: req.body.type,
      size: req.body.size,
      condition: req.body.condition,
      year: req.body.year,
      moveableFrom: req.body.moveableFrom,
      numberOfRooms: req.body.numberOfRooms,
      furnitured: req.body.furnitured,
      elevator: req.body.elevator,
      level: req.body.level,
      garden: req.body.garden,
      attic: req.body.attic,
      pet: req.body.pet,
      smoke: req.body.smoke
    });
    prop.save();.then(updatedProperty => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "Property added successfully",
        prop: {
          ...updatedProperty,
          id: updatedProperty._id
        }
      });
    });
  }
);
```

When I console.log the req.body here i will get an empty object, but it just worked fine when i conole.log it in the frontend in the service.ts file.

What could cause this problem?

Comment: Try sending post data as JSON objects.

Comment: With JSON.stringify?

Comment: No, I mean, instead of sending FormData bojects, send it as JSON and try.

Comment: Yeah, it is working now, Thank you!

Comment: Great, you can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post the data as JSON objects, instead of sending it as FormData objects.